# NSString stringWithFormat - trying to set a label to double digits for single digit numbers

Tags: objective-c, stringwithformat

I am trying to have a label display single-digit numbers as double-digit numbers (ie. 1 => 01)  . I may be using the wrong method to set the value for the label but the thing is I'm not even sure about that after pouring over Apple's documentation and scouring the internet.

```
[secondsLabel setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", seconds]]
```

I saw someone else's use of stringWithFormat as stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" so I figured I would try something similar and change it to "%2d", no luck. Thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You were very close: try `"%.2d"` (note the ".").

The reference for the format string in the `-stringWithFormat:` method is the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)

Comment: +1 for the dot for leading zeros. I thought they were for post decimal point precision/rounding. I've always used `"%02d"` to achieve the same thing